# Force close when going from ViewPager to NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

This may be a bit hard to explain but here goes. First you need to know how my app is set up.

LoginPage > ViewPager tutorial (contains 4 fragments) > Navigation drawer.

On the last Fragment in the ViewPager there's a button to confirm you have completed the tutorial. The problem comes about when you want to see the tutorial again. I added it into my navigation drawer because I wanted users to be able to go back to the tutorial. I get a force close error when the users presses the button on the 4th Fragment saying they have seen the tutorial. This error only happens when going to the tutorial for a second time, through the navigation drawer.

Here is how you get to it:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Fragment newFragment = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch(i) {
            case 0:
                newFragment = new FragmentTwo();
                fm.popBackStack();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, newFragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                newFragment = new FragmentThree();
                fm.popBackStack();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, newFragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                newFragment = new FragmentFour();
                fm.popBackStack();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, newFragment).addToBackStack("fragback").commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent goToTut = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentPagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToTut);
                //fm.popBackStack();
                break;
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(rl);
```

**case 3:

Intent goToTut = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentPagerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goToTut);**

The error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package.name, PID: 3379
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.inter.space.NavDrawer}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
at com.package.name.PostLogin.onCreate(PostLogin.java:98)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-29 10:20:08.852: E/AndroidRuntime(3379):     ... 11 more
```

I think the error is because I am trying to open the NavigationDrawer from a different place where it tries to create a new instance of it when really, it's already running. Is there a way that I can solve this issue?

I would really appreciate some help on this, because I am lost. Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the code of PostLogin and indicate line 98

Comment: Line 98: Log.i("Facebook id:", pId); That pId comes from an Intent on the ViewPager. My PostLogin is quite big. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: `pld` is null. check it

Comment: That.. would make sense. When the user logs in, all that information is collected. If they are already logged in and just viewing the tut again, it won't pull that info again. I think SharedPrefs might be the way to go.

Comment: I removed the intents that collect pId and removed them from PostLogin, and now the FragmentPagerActivity works without error. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Please add an answer and I'll accept I think I'll use SharedPrefs from the start. (I'm actually putting pId into SharedPrefs later on in PostLogin)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments line 98 is

```
 Log.i("Facebook id:", pId);
```

So `pld` is null. You log says that needs a message to print.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Check and make sure `pld` is not null